# Hadoop 2.0. Does it support new MapReduce 2 only or both classic and new MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Does Hadoop 2.0 support new MapReduce 2 (YARN) only or both classic and new MapReduce?

Answer (score 2):

It supports both. The difference is that what you call classic mapreduce will now run as an *application* instead of integrated as part of the framework.

YARN allows the community to build other *mapreduce-like* applications to run on the Hadoop platform.

An example of another MR2 application can be found in the first link below called DIstributedShell

[Brief Explanation MR2 and YARN](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/mr2-and-yarn-briefly-explained/)

The very bottom of this article states it explicitly. All anyone changing to MRv2 would have to do is recompile their source code and it should run.

[More Detailed Explanation](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/02/mapreduce-2-0-in-hadoop-0-23/)